# Why isn't anything being written to my file?

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm making a program with OpenCV and I want to record the X,Y coordinates of the two objects I'm tracking. I've retrieved the data just fine and am using it to display the coordinates on-screen, however I've been struggling to write it to a log file.

I have a function which I pass all the relevant data to, and I am sure my program is reaching the function because the file is being created.

Can somebody please tell me why `"test.txt"` is empty? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
void saveData(int leftX, int leftY, int rightX, int rightY, int distance){
    logfile.open("test.txt");

    //Timer
    time_t start = time(0); //Set initial time point

    //Counter
    int counter = 0;

    //String for coordinates
    //String for coordinates
string coords = "Left X: " + intToString(leftX) + "  LeftY: " + intToString(leftY) +
    "  Right X: " + intToString(rightX) + "  Right Y: " + intToString(rightY) + "  Distance between: " + intToString(distance) + "\n";

    //If 1 minute has passed
    if (start - time(0) == 60){

        //Write coordinates to log file
        logfile << coords;

        //Increment counter
        counter++;

        //After 30 mins of recording exit program
        if (counter == 30){
            //Close the log file
            logfile.close();

            //Exit with no errors
            exit(0);
        }

        //Reset time to 0
        start = time(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this function called? Do you have a loop anywhere?

Comment: if (start - time(0) == 60) will never evaluate to true, because you just set start to time(0). Having failed, the function exits and nothing is written. Also, it should be (time(0) - start) or you will get negative values in the case that time(0) had increased.

Comment: @Vinzenz this function is called within a function that is called from an infinite loop inside my main function

Comment: Step through your code using a debugger and check to see if the variables contain the values you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C and C++ variables created in the stack (aka non pointer variables) are confined to their scope.
I suppose that your function will be called inside an external loop.
The counter will NOT be seen by the loop. Same for start.

Moreover there are some logical issues in your code:

1. start-time(0)==60 will be tested only once. time(0) will always be greater than start.
2. counter will only increment to 1 (and won't since start-time(0)<0) since it isn't inside a loop, but only in a if clause.

I can suggest a pseudocode based on what I've intended you wanna do from the code you posted up there:

```
void saveData(data){
    open file

    setup start=time(0) and counter=0

    format the output string

    while(counter<=30){
        if((int)(time(0)-start)%60==0){ //seconds_passed=60*N, N integer
            write data
            counter++
        }    
    }

    close the file
}
```

Have fun

gf

EDIT:
if you call this function from an external infinite loop you have to pass counter by reference (so increments inside the function will be seen from outside) and start as argument.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you call this function in an infinite loop (as you said in the comment), maybe you should consider not to open the file on each call.

Second, checking for exactly 1 minute to pass can fail, because there might be more than one second passing between two checks. In this case you would not write to the file ever. It is better to check if more than one minute has passed.

Finally, your actual problem (as mentioned by samgak) is that

```
start - time(0)
```

will be negative and instead you should do

```
if (time(0) - start > 60)
```

EDIT: I just realized another problem with your code:

```
//Timer
time_t start = time(0); //Set initial time point
// ...
//If 1 minute has passed
if (start - time(0) == 60){
```

You are actually checking if 1 minute has passed between this two lines. Provided that there is little happening between this two lines, it is unlikely, that you ever write to the file.

Also

```
start = time(0)
```

at the end has no effect.